# Who is Kaal Purush?

Tags: hanuman, ravana

I watch the TV Series called [Jai Jai Jai Bajrang Bali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jai_Jai_Jai_Bajrang_Bali).

There Ravana (king of Lanka) tries to stop *Kaal Purush* after *Kaal Purush* denies to answer Ravana's questions. He is shown as a person who rides on a black horse and moves across the universe continuously. He carries a black staff.

I tried finding online about him but couldn't find any.

Who is **Kaal Purush**?

Comment: Can you add a picture or share episodes link where it is shown?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto https://youtu.be/OhWxTYLlklQ